# PhantomJS screenshots not showing text

Tags: phantomjs, screenshot, text-rendering

I'm using PhantomJS to run some automated tests through Codeception. When I generate a screenshot however the page shows but none of the text does, like the sample below.

[image]

Here is the script I use to install phantomjs.  I'm using CentOS 7.1

```
echo "## Install phantomjs dependencies"
sudo yum install freetype-devel fontconfig-devel libicu-devel gcc glib libpng-devel bison sqlite-devel gperf flex libjpeg-devel  -y

echo "## Install phantomjs"
cd ~
PHANTOM_JS="phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64"
wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/$PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2
sudo mv $PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2 /usr/local/share/
cd /usr/local/share/
sudo tar xvjf $PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/share/$PHANTOM_JS/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/share/phantomjs
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/share/$PHANTOM_JS/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/share/$PHANTOM_JS/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs
sudo rm -fr $PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2
phantomjs -v
```

My initial thought was I'm missing a font library but from what I can read on the [phantomjs site](http://phantomjs.org/build.html) I should have all the packages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So it looks like my version of [CentOS](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/bento/boxes/centos-7.1) does not actually have any fonts installed.  Adding the following lines to my PhantomJS install script added some fonts to the system and the screenshots worked as expected.

```
sudo yum install cabextract xorg-x11-font-utils -y
sudo rpm -i https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mscorefonts2/rpms/msttcore-fonts-installer-2.6-1.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: It was a bit edge case when I had some fonts installed and only text in inputs didn't appear. Anyway `yum install liberation-mono-fonts liberation-sans-fonts liberation-serif-fonts` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't see the text in the screenshots after installing fonts, make sure that you are using the correct user-agent that tells what is the OS that your machine is running on.
E.g:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36
```

- with this one I CAN'T see the text.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.0 Safari/537.36
```

- with this one I see the text.

I'm using Linux CentOS.